# How do I get the amplitude of a variable sine function?

Tags: control-theory, parameter-estimation, optimal-control, fast-fourier-transform, system-identification

Let's assume that we have a dynamical system

$$G(s) = \frac{Y(s)}{U(s)}$$

And we have measure the input $u(t)$

[image]

And we have measure the output $y(t)$.

[image]

Here we can see that if we increase the frequency at the input of the system, the output is going to decrease.

The question is simple: How can I find the amplitudes over time of by just knowing $y(t)$ and $u(t)$. Nothing more.

My goal is to estimate a transfer function from arbitrary frequency input and output and I going to use least square to curve fit on a transfer function.

Can I just drag a line of all peaks/tops of the sine waves?

Comment: Maybe it is just me but: can you please clarify what you are working with? The notation makes me think that it is $Y(s)=\mathcal L\{y(t)\}$ and $U(s)=\mathcal L\{u(t)\}$ but you have fft in the tags

Comment: I did a simple System ID in Python [suggestions-for-fitting-noisy-exponentials-with-scipy-curve-fit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42407051/suggestions-for-fitting-noisy-exponentials-with-scipy-curve-fit/42500533#42500533)  which massages the data to be smoothly periodic, and takes ratio of ffts of U and Y - for your frequency sweep I would time reverse, invert and concatenate the time series before the fft, and fit the ratio to a Laplace domain transfer function for a shelving low pass filter

Comment: @Holo I doing system identification of a transfer function into frequency plane.

Comment: @f5r5e5d Did it work well ?

Comment: @DanielMårtensson both transform are doing this...

Comment: I did not get the question. You have a time domain response and you are after identification of the frequency domain transfer function?

Comment: @ArashMohammadi Yes, I want to find the amplitudes so I can build my transfer function.

Comment: @DanielMårtensson, how about this [theory](https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/ee/ee392m/ee392m.1034/Lecture8_ID.pdf) and [coding](https://au.mathworks.com/help/ident/gs/about-system-identification.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have $u(t)$ and $y(t)$, you can compute the Laplace transform of each and get, by your first equation,

$$
G(s) = \frac{L(y(t))}{L(u(t))}.
$$

If your measurements are continuous time and perfect then this is exact. If you have noisy measurements, then this is approximate. If you have discrete measurements you need to look at Hankel matrices and realization theory.